# getting attachement images src and add classes

Tags: attachments, array, images

I have posts whose each contains 4 attached images.
what i'm trying to do in my single.php is to get all the 4 images src to be abble to add different classes to each images.

```
<img class="image_1 no_lazy" src="first attached image src"/>
<img class="image_2" src="second attached image src"/>
<img class="image_3" src="third attached image src"/>
<img class="image_4" src="fourth attached image src"/>
```

here is what I've tried, but I get an array instead of getting the src... I think I'm really close to the solution, but I can't find out what I am doin wrong...

```
<?php
  global $post;
  $args = array( 
    'post_parent' => $post->ID, 
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'numberposts' => 4 );
   $images = get_posts($args); ?>

<img class="image_1 no_lazy" src="<?php  echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( $images[0]->ID, 'full' ); ?>"/>
<img class="image_2" src="<?php  echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( $images[1]->ID, 'full' ); ?>"/>
<img class="image_3" src="<?php  echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( $images[2]->ID, 'full' ); ?>"/>
<img class="image_4" src="<?php  echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( $images[3]->ID, 'full' ); ?>"/>
```

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks

Answer (score 13):

If you only want to add an extra class, then you should use `wp_get_attachment_image`. It has few extra params, and the last one is used for setting class names.

Sample usage:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail', "", ["class" => "my-custom-class"] ); ?>
```

The main advantage of this aproach is that you will also get the whole `srcset` attributes for free.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_get_attachment_image_src` returns an array with 3 elements; the image URL, the width, and the height. You need to echo the first index of the result.

In fact, you can make your code a little leaner by using a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ( $images as $i => $image ) {
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'full' );

    echo '<img class="image_' . ++$i;
    if ( $i === 1 )
        echo ' no_lazy';
    echo '" src="' . $src[0] . '" />';
}
```

Comment: if you just need the URL you can use `wp_get_attachment_image_url()`